# Extraction particulars from a text file using python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a .txt file in which the content are of this type:

```
DIRN straight-2
FOR minutes-5
DO crossing-6
WHAT Hall-7-13
DO take-10
WHAT Hall-3-15
```

What I want is another .txt file that can be generated with the help of python which will have this as its final content:

```
DIRN straight
FOR minutes
DO crossing
WHAT Hall-7
DO take
WHAT Hall-3
```

ie, I want to remove everything that comes after the last hyphen "-" in each line including hyphen also.

Please help me with the python code and thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @Todd I have tried using rstrip('-') but its not working somehow.
Help me with something else.

Answer (score 7):

In Python 2 or 3, this works:

```
s='''DIRN straight-2
FOR minutes-5
DO crossing-6
WHAT Hall-7-13
DO take-10
WHAT Hall-3-15'''

import re

for line in s.splitlines():
    line=re.sub(r'^(.*)-\d+$',r'\1',line)
    print line
```

You can do a non regex in Python this way:

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    line=line.rpartition('-')[0] if '-' in line else line
    print(line)
```

Or -- probably better still:

```
for line in s.splitlines():
    line=line[:line.rindex("-")] if '-' in line else line    
    print line
```

The regex is more specific since it only matches `-\d+` at the end of the string.

Any case, prints:

```
DIRN straight
FOR minutes
DO crossing
WHAT Hall-7
DO take
WHAT Hall-3
```

Comment: I'd write the non-regex version as `line[:line.rindex("-")] if '-' in line else line`.

Comment: @DSM: Thanks! That is a good addition.